# Memcached error in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memcached, jruby

I have the rails application with Jruby. i do the Active record cache by using memcached. i installed memcache-client gem. since i am connecting memcache server to remote host. my memcache config are as follows in my development.rb:

```
require 'memcache'

memcache_options = {
  :c_threshold => 10_000,
  :compression => true,
  :debug => false,
  :namespace => "#{RAILS_ENV}",
  :readonly => false,
  :urlencode => false,
  :timeout => 60
}

CACHE = MemCache.new memcache_options
CACHE.servers = 'example.org:0000'

config.action_controller.cache_store = CACHE, {}
```

When I try to access the page, I get the follwiwng error message on my terminal :

```
MemCache::MemCacheError in ExampleController#index 
Resource temporarily unavailable -
```

I did the telnet example.org 1000 . it works fine and type the command 'stats' will give the successful output.

I am using windows vista... i cann't check my firewall config...i guess if firewall blocks i couldn't even do telnet.  Is it i have to open my port on my development machine ? or what else the problem i couldn't figure out.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly encourage you to use [Dalli](https://github.com/mperham/dalli).

```
config.cache_store = :dalli_store, 'cache-1.example.com', 'cache-2.example.com',
{ :namespace => NAME_OF_RAILS_APP, :expires_in => 1.day, :compress => true, :compress_threshold => 64*1024 }
```

Otherwise, use the `:memcached_store` option to configure Memcached.

```
config.action_controller.cache_store = :memcached_store
```

To debug the error, open a new Rails console

```
# rails 3
$ rails c

# rails 2
$ ruby script/console
```

and try to access `Rails.cache`. See if it works.

Comment: Hi Simone, Thanks for you commend. Will "config.action_controller.cache_store = :memcached_store" will helps? If yes, should i comment out the previous declarations  and use this declaration only?

Comment: Also Ruby console(Rails 2) returns me the following:

Comment: #<ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore:0x1bb8ea @data={}>

Comment: If it returns a MemoryStore, it means it doesn't use Memcached at all. Make sure your environment has the right `cache_store` set.

Comment: Will you please give the full detail. how should i declare and myapplication get knowledge of memcached .Pls help me out .

Comment: I explained you in my answer and in my comments above.

Comment: Yes i declare config.cache_store = :memcached_store. and open my console try that now #<ActiveSupport::Cache::MemcacheStore:0x1bb8ea @data={}> but still get "Resource Temporarily unavailable" ... I wan t to implement on my development environments.

Comment: Try `Rails.cache.stats` and see if it can connects to Memcached. If it can't, then check your memcached config.

Comment: While doing Rails.cache.stats, i get the following.

Comment: >> Rails.cache
=> #<ActiveSupport::Cache::MemCacheStore:0x1301061>
>> Rails.cache.stats
MemCache::MemCacheError: Resource temporarily unavailable -
        from c:/jruby-1.5.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/memcache-client-1.8.3/lib/mem
cache.rb:1131:in `read_nonblock'

Comment: but when i try with telnet it works fine stats command returns the result for me.

Comment: Memcached configured in remote server... i try to connect from my local, on my local i am not installed memcached, i guess it is not necessary . my Rails config is  memcache_options = {
 :c_threshold => 10_000,
   :compression => true,
  :debug => false,
  :namespace => "#{RAILS_ENV}",
  :readonly => false,
  :urlencode => false,
  :timeout => 60
 }

CACHE = MemCache.new memcache_options
CACHE.servers = 'eample.org:17898'
#config.action_controller.cache_store = CACHE, {}

config.cache_store =:mem_cache_store